# How to find database name for exchange server using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

I'm creating a mailbox for a user in ActiveDirectory using LDAP with C#. While creating the mailbox, we need to set the "homeMDB" attribute. The syntax for "homeMDB" is

> CN=DB1,CN=SG1,CN=InformationStore,CN=Exchange1,CN=Servers,CN=AG1,CN=Administrative
>   Groups,CN=Organization,CN=Microsoft
>   Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com

where "DB1" is the database name of the Exchange server.

Can anyone please tell me how to find the database name for the Exchange server programatically using C#?

Answer (score 0):

The `displayName` and/or `name` attributes will be useful here. All of the databases are located in the general area you've highlighted. You'll have to search under each server and storage group. As your on Exchange 2003 or 2007 by the looks of it, keep in mind that database names aren't globally unique.